# How to checkout svn files to another directory other than the current

Tags: svn

When we use `svn checkout`, it always checks out files to the current directory.

How can we checkout files to anther directory?  I have read `svn help checkout`, but I couldn't find an option to let me do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
svn co url://some/url name-of-directory-you-want
```

From `svn help checkout`:

```
$ svn help checkout
checkout (co): Check out a working copy from a repository.
usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]

  If specified, REV determines in which revision the URL is first
  looked up.

  If PATH is omitted, the basename of the URL will be used as
  the destination. If multiple URLs are given each will be checked
  out into a sub-directory of PATH, with the name of the sub-directory
  being the basename of the URL.
```

That last argument you see (`[PATH]`) is the path to the directory where you want it to be checked out.

Comment: i didn't notice this [path], thank you!